# Form validation, missing fields background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how to set an alert to if the field is blank or wrong characters then it will alert them. But I don't want an alert pop up, I want all of the missing fields to be a different background color.

```
function allLetter(uname)  
{   
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(uname.value.match(letters))  
{  
return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert('name required');  
uname.focus();  
return false;  
}
```

However, when I change the alert to,

```
alert(document.style.display.backgroundColor = red)
```

then nothing will happen at all. It wont even show the alert for the other missing fields. Also, if both the name and the email are wrong then it will only alert for the name and not the email, since the name is first

Comment: What you need to do is create a loop that iterates through all the fields and changes the background color of each field that is missing the required information. If you include your HTML, CSS, and any other Javascript, then I will be able to assist you more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want.

```
       function allLetter(uname)  
    {    
     var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
     if(uname.value.match(letters)) {   
               return true;  
     } else{  
     uname.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      uname.focus();  
      return false;  
   }
```